Definability of the class of Hausdorff topological spaces using the closure operator in a first-order way.
Recall the Kuratowski closure axioms for general topological spaces:

$f(0)=0$, where $0$ is the empty set
$x \subseteq f(x)$
$f(x)=f(f(x))$
$f(x \cup y) = f(x) \cup f(y)$

The question I am interested in now, is whether the subclass of Hausdorff topological spaces can be characterized by adding more axioms. Let be a little more precise. Let our first-order signature be  $\{0,1,f,\subseteq,\cup,\cap)$, where $0$ is the empty set, $1$ is the universal set, $f$ is the closure operation, $\subseteq$ is subset, $\cup$ is binary union, and $\cap$ is binary intersection. In that signature, can the class of Hausdorff topological spaces be characterized in terms of a first-order set of axioms? Certain subclasses of topological spaces can. For example, the discrete topological spaces can be characterized by the additional axiom $f(x)=x$. Also, the indiscrete topological spaces can be characterized by the additional axiom $x \neq 0 \rightarrow f(x)=1$. I suspect Hausdorff spaces can't be characterized by a set of first-order axioms, but I want a proof that it can't. And if it can, I would like to see a set of axioms that do characterize it, along with the proof that it does.

You might find it useful to look into "closure algebras". This is discussed by Bezhanishvili and van Benthem in  "Modal Logics of Space", and briefly in these notes https://rodrigonalmeida.github.io/projects/Topology_Project/Guest-lecture-slides.pdf.
It is shown there that there is no equational axiomatization of Hausdorff spaces. The argument there also shows that there cannot be any universal axiomatization of Hausdorff spaces within closure algebras. I don't think anybody has studied first-order definability in this signature, in this line of research, but it's an interesting question!

You want a formulation in terms of the partial order of all subsets together with the closure operator.
We get the elements of the space as the atoms of the partial order. Containment of elements corresponds to the subset relation for atoms.
This means we can just directly translate the definition of being Hausdorff. If there are two distinct atoms $x$ and $y$, then there must be two closed subsets $A,B$ whose union is the whole space and such $x \not\subseteq A$ and $y \not\subseteq B$.
Maybe not what you were looking for I assume, since this is not just talking about how the closure operator behaves on general sets. But I doubt we can do it this way. T1 means that all atoms are closed. Normal topological spaces can be defined without atoms.
